# How to re-arrange git release branch(es) after many branches have been merged?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-merge, git-branch

I've got a git situation that has come up that I'm not sure how to handle. I've got two release branches that have changed due to UAT/QA not being able to properly test the changes in time for the Production release schedule. Basically, they rejected some of my development work and accepted some others from a more high priority project. Luckily, I've placed my code in various feature branches. I now know not to merge any of my feature branches until they accept the work. A partial list of these branches is shown below.

The first time they rejected features, I removed the release/2104 (2021 April) branch and then recreated it. This worked fairly easily, as I only had one or two feature branches to merge. I think I had to make a special patch branch to make sure some of my changes got added to the release. I'm not sure if this was the best approach. I'm fairly certain that it has screwed up the merge history for this branch.

- release/2103

  - feature/jjwalte-DA-44948
- release/2104

  - feature/jjwalte-DA-45102
  - feature/jjwalte-DA-45102-2 (special path branch)
- release/2105

  - feature/jjwalte-DA-44971
  - feature/jjwalte-DA-45008
  - and several others...

Looking forward to the release/2105, I'm all mixed up. I'm not sure if I can rely on the merge history anymore. I was thinking that the best approach might be to rename the current release/2105 branch to release/2105-old (local and remote) and then create a new release/2105 branch from release/2104. We don't have a big team (2 or 3 people max), so it should be simple to get everyone to rename it locally.

Note, I've got about 9 branches that are supposed to go out with release/2105 branch release. Some of my branches were branched off of release/2104 and others were branched off of release/2105. I think this is one of my biggest problems. What do you think is the best approach for this mess?

My current plan for release/2105:

So, first will be rename:

```
git branch -m release/2105 release/2105-old
git checkout release/2105-old
```

Then delete the remote:

```
git push origin :release/2105
```

Then set tracking:

```
git push --set-upstream origin release/2105-old
```

Then I'll create a new 2105 branch off of the 2104 branch.

```
git checkout release/2104

git checkout -b release/2105
git push --set-upstream origin release/2105
```

Then... I'm going to try to use SourceTree (app) to "Cherry Pick" various commits (50+) for the new release/2105 branch.

Hopefully, if all goes well... I'll have a release/2105 branch
with just the tickets/commits I need for the release.

Comment: What branching strategy are you using?

Comment: @TTT It's, more or less, a git flow like branching strategy.

Comment: You have 3 different release branches now, and none of them have been deployed yet? All of them *might* still be deployed? In the future when they are deployed, will they all be deployed to the same place? (The first thing to get deployed gets replaced by the second deployment, which is replaced by the third deployment.)

Comment: @TTT The March release (release/2103) just got released, so that one is set. DevOps has Jenkins setup for the deployments of the project (one application - all same place). As long as I have those release branch naming conventions, it can get deployed. I guess my main question is: Is it better to rename and create new release branches or delete and recreate the release branches?

Comment: The preferred approach to dealing with this is to practice true continuous integration. Isolate new work behind feature toggles and keep your feature branches integrated. If the feature fails QA or for whatever reason isn't functioning to expectations, simply **disable** it.

Comment: I think the confusion here is that you have potentially 2 release branches going at the same time. It's much easier to just have 1. Do you really need 2? (Best practice would dictate that is should be pretty rare to actually need 2 simultaneously.) Also, why even bother renaming the release branch at all? If you have a release branch that people are using, can't you just leave it until it's released? The name of the branch shouldn't matter once you complete it anyway.

Comment: Side note, if you're using Git Flow with --no-ff for PR merge commits, you may not want to cherry pick an old release branch into a new one, since you'll lose the information contained within those merge commits.

Comment: @TTT - There can be multiple release branches going. To make matters worse, devops has the names tied down so that auto deployments can be done. Anyways, I renamed the old release branch and created a new one. Then I had to cherry-pick into a new feature branch and then merge that feature branch into the new release branch.